# Subscriber's messages transport through UDP

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

Is there a possiblity to send Data through UDP from a ROS Node to the other non-ROS PC?

To specify my question : I have used the subscriber to subscribe the lidar's scan topic successfully,

and I want to pass the messages of the scanning data from my subscriber through the UDP protocol to the other one non-ROS computer.

I see [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/UDPROS) page regarding UDPROS but there seems to be little, new information.

Does anyone know or have used this before? I would be thankful if someone can direct me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223345/subscriber%27s-messages-transport-through-udp/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UDPROS can only be used for sending data over ROS topics.

If you want to send data to a non-ROS computer, you should create a normal UDP socket and write data to it. Using raw UDP sockets isn't within the scope of this forum, and there are already lots of other good examples of how to use UDP from Python or C++ on the internet.

The first few links on Google all look like good places to start: https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20create%20a%20udp%20socket%20in%20c&rct=j

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-03**:
@ahendrix, If I need to use UDP to transport the data of subscriber, do I just need to put the UDP code in the subscriber's roscpp? Sorry I'm not familiar about the C code and I'm a ROS newbie, hope you can help me about these questions. Thanks in advanced.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-03**:
Yes. If you want to use UDP you'll need to write the UDP code in your subscriber.